# Translate form to custom set locale

Tags: php, symfony

Hi i have a use case where i want to translate form to the custom locale then that one set in request

I tried to do something like

```
$tmpLocale = $request->getLocale();
$request->setLocale('es');
$form = $this->createForm(new DataType());
$formView = $form->renderView();
$request->setLocale($tmpLocale);

return $this->render('AppBundle:Data:edit.html.twig', array(
    'data' => $data,
    'form' => $formView,
));
```

but it doesnt work, how can i make it work this ?
i need form labels to be translated as this custom locale.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did it by simple change locale at translator service.

```
$tmpLocale = $this->get('translator')->getLocale();
$this->get('translator')->setLocale('es');
$form = $this->createForm(new DataType());
$formView = $form->createView();
$this->get('translator')->setLocale($tmpLocale);
```

And this works fine. No need for advanced solution.

Answer (score 1):

The form label translation is made in form rendering. If it is a common use case in your application then you might consider override the behavior by translating labels:

[Create a new form type extension](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/form/create_form_type_extension.html) and pass the `locale` variable to template layout:

```
class FormTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view->vars['locale'] = $options['locale'];
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        // define locale option for each form field.
        // if null the labels are translates to current locale.
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('locale' => null));
    }

    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return 'form';
    }
}
```

The service:

```
services:
    app.form.extension.locale:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Extension\FormTypeExtension
        tags:
            - { name: form.type_extension, alias: form }
```

Next, [overrides all form blocks](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/form/form_customization.html#form-customization-form-themes) that include `trans()` function and adds `locale` as third parameter:

```
{{ label|trans({}, translation_domain, locale) }}
```

[Sample](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig#L227):

```
{%- block form_label -%}
    {% if label is not same as(false) -%}
        {# ... #}
        <label ... >{{ translation_domain is same as(false) ? label : label|trans({}, translation_domain, locale) }}</label>
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endblock form_label -%}
```

Later, you can use `locale` option for each form field:

```
$form->add('name', null, array('locale' => 'es'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [TranslatorInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Translation/TranslatorInterface.html#method_trans), its fourth parameter is `locale` which you can directly use to translate messages.
You need to register your form type as a service, inject translator (and perhaps custom locale) to it and translate all messages inside using this locale.

Comment: this could lead to double translation?

Comment: @Yonel what do you mean by "double translation"?

Comment: `... and translate all messages inside using this locale.` if the labels are translated directly this could be made twice, you need setting `translation_domain` to `false` to avoid it.